# How to build a 3D view with RealSense R200

Tags: ros, 3dcamera, intel, realsense-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I've installed everything included in https://github.com/PercATI/RealSense_ROS and I'm able to launch

```
roslaunch realsense realsense_r200_launch.launch
```

without problems or errors.

Since I would like to use my Realsense R200 to build a 3D view of my environment in RVIZ, I tried to load the **realsenseRvizConfiguration.rviz** configuration file as the author suggests in his tutorial.

When I load this file, I get this error: " Fixed Frame [world] does not exist " and " For frame [camera_depth_optical_frame]: Fixed Frame [world] does not exist" as you can see in the attached screenshot.
[screenshot.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14636770835830183.png)
This is my **view_frames** output: [view_frames.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14636772539838179.png).

I noticed that there is no world frame, but I don't know how to load it in my tf tree.

I would like to build a 3D view like it is shown in http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense_R200?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=snapshot.png.

In addition, do you think it's possible to move the sensor around a room and build a 3D map?

Thank you for your time,

Rocco Galati

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234715/how-to-build-a-3d-view-with-realsense-r200/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-05-19**:
I modified my question since now I'm able to correctly run the sensor node, but I'm still not able to build a 3D view in RVIZ. Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fixed frame relative to which all data is shown in rviz is set to `world`, but your realsense camera frames do not have a tf connection to that frame, so data cannot be displayed correctly. If you enter `realsense_frame` as fixed frame in rviz, you should see sensor data.

You can probably build a 3D map using the Realsense, but this generally is not trivial. There are multiple packages that probably can be set up to work with the R200, such as [RGBD-SLAM](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2), [RTABMAP](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap) (for that see [this Q/A)](http://answers.ros.org/question/218957/realsense-r200-with-rtabmap-rgbd-odometry/), [viso2](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2) and others. All of them require some setup effort however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-05-20**:
Yes, if I specify realsese_frame as fixed frame I can see some data coming from the sensor, but they dont create a 3D view since they change while I move the camera sensor. So, if I want to have a 3D view or map, should I use RTABMAP? It works also with the realsense or only with Kinect?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-05-20**:
Looks like it should work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc1WhmFCjcc

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-05-20**:
I watched the same video before and I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Unfortunately, there is no so much literature on this topic :( If I will have problems, can you help me, please? Are you confident with this theme?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-05-20**:
I don't have time to give detailed assistance. You might want to check out the rtabmap forum however. See for instance http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/ROS-2D-occupancy-grid-td1204.html